# How to use two (multiple) Liferay UI Search Container tags in a single JSP

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to use two different `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tags in a single JSP.

The pagination gives issues if we use two `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tags:

1. When I click on the 3rd page of the first `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tag the second `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tag also moves to the third page.
2. Also if for the first `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tag I am on page-3 and I click page-2 of second `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tag then the second tag goes to page-2 but the first tag results is reset to page-1.

They should be independent of each other.

Environment: Liferay 6.+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found two different ways to do this:

1. This is possible through the use of **`curParam`** attribute in `<liferay-ui:search-container>` tag, noticed the `curParam="folderCurParam"` and `curParam="fileCurParam"` in the following code, I found this way through liferay's source code `docroot/html/portlet/document_library_display/view.jsp` and `docroot/html/portlet/document_library_display/view_file_entries.jspf`:

   ```
   <liferay-ui:search-container
           curParam="folderCurParam"
           emptyResultsMessage="no-folders-to-display"  
           iteratorURL="<%= portletURL %>"
           delta="10">

       <liferay-ui:search-container-results
               results="<%=folderResults %>"
               total="<%= folderTotal %>" />

       <liferay-ui:search-container-row
               className="com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.Folder"
               keyProperty="userId"
               modelVar="folder">

           <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp align="left"
                   path="/html/documentdisplay/folder_search_results.jsp" />

       </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

       <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

   </liferay-ui:search-container>

   <liferay-ui:search-container
           curParam="fileCurParam"
           emptyResultsMessage="no-files-to-display" 
           iteratorURL="<%= portletURL %>"
           delta="10">
       <liferay-ui:search-container-results
               results="<%=fileResults %>"
               total="<%= fileTotal %>" />

       <liferay-ui:search-container-row
               className="com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry"
               keyProperty="userId"
               modelVar="fileEntry">

           <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp align="left"
                   path="/html/documentdisplay/files_search_results.jsp" />

       </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

       <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

   </liferay-ui:search-container>
   ```
2. I found this again in liferay's source code `docroot/html/portlet/journal/select_document_library.jsp`, this uses the **[`SearchContainer` constructor](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/SearchContainer.html#SearchContainer%28javax.portlet.PortletRequest,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.search.DisplayTerms,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.search.DisplayTerms,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.portlet.PortletURL,%20java.util.List,%20java.lang.String%29)** to set the `curParam`, notice the parameter `"cur1"` for folders and for files it is `"cur2"`:

   ```
   // for folders
   SearchContainer searchContainer = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, "cur1", SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, portletURL, headerNames, "there-are-no-folders");

   // for files
   searchContainer = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, "cur2", SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, portletURL, headerNames, "there-are-no-documents-in-this-folder");
   ```

Hope this helps someone.